# ¿Cómo colocar la codificación UTF-8 en este caso?

Tags: java, codificación

Llevo ya un rato probando de colocar la codificación *UTF-8* a mi proyecto pero no da resultado. Dejo los códigos.

Clase que se encarga de abrir y guardar el archivo de la interfaz:

```
package Clases;

import java.io.*;


public class GestionCheats {
    FileInputStream entrada;
    FileOutputStream salida;
    File archivo;

    public GestionCheats(){

    }

    /*Abrir un archivo de texto*/
    public String AbrirATexto(File archivo){
        String contenido="";
        try {
            entrada = new FileInputStream(archivo);
            int ascci;
            while((ascci = entrada.read())!= -1){
                char carcater = (char)ascci;
                contenido += carcater;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return contenido;
    }

    /*Guardar archivo de texto*/
    public String GuardarATexto(File archivo, String contenido){
        String respuesta=null;
        try {
            salida = new FileOutputStream(archivo);
            byte[] bytesTxt = contenido.getBytes();
            salida.write(bytesTxt);
            respuesta = "Se guardo con exito el archivo";
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return respuesta;
    }
    public String GuardarAImagen(File archivo, byte[] bytesImg){
        String respuesta=null;
        try {
            salida = new FileOutputStream(archivo);

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return respuesta;
    }
}
```

... y aquí tengo el código de la interfaz:

```
private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    if(seleccionado.showDialog(null, "ABRIR ARCHIVO") == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        archivo = seleccionado.getSelectedFile();
        if(archivo.canRead()){
            if(archivo.getName().endsWith("ps4codedbs")){

                String contenido = gestion.AbrirATexto(archivo);
                jTextArea1.setText(contenido);

                String tituloarchivo=seleccionado.getSelectedFile().getName();
                txttitle.setText(tituloarchivo);

                try
                {
                    FileReader fr = new FileReader(archivo);
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);  
                    ArrayList<String> records = new ArrayList<String>();

                    String line = null;

                    while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        records.add(line);
                    }
                    for(int i = 0; i < records.size(); i++)
                    {
                        String[] array = records.get(1).split(";");
                        String[] array1 = records.get(0).split(";");

                        txtcode.setText(array1[1].trim());
                        txttitulo.setText(array[1].trim());
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException ioe)
                {
                    System.out.println("algo no va bien...");//temporary
                } 
                //
            }else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Elegir un archivo .ps4codedbs");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

¿Cómo puedo ubicar en ese código que el botón de **abrir** que mostré en el código interfaz me abra el archivo dentro de una ubicación específica? Dicho de otro modo, quiero que cuando cliquee en abrir se abra una carpeta en concreto. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que el archivo cuando le cliquee en **guardar** se guarde con un nombre específico? En este caso con el contenido del `jTextField ID`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para guardar un archivo en formato utf8 es mejor que uses `OutputStreamWriter` en porque soporta codificación. Puedes usarlo así:

```
OutputStreamWriter outputStream = new OutputStreamWriter(
     new FileOutputStream("mifichero.txt"),
     Charset.forName("UTF-8").newEncoder() 
 );
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta Fernando, eso iria en la clase que abre y guarda los archivos deduzco, por que código tendría que reemplazarlo? y tambien tengo que hacer lo mismo con el inputstream?

Comment: Si, tendrías que cambiarlo en los métodos AbrirATexto y GuardarATexto. Tendrías que cambiar el FileInputStream también si quieres que te lea el fichero que has guardado en UTF8. Pruebalo y me cuentas.

Comment: Estuve colocando los codigos y parece que conseguí el input, pero con el output tengo problemas, al guardar el archivo borra el contenido

Comment: Mmmm, podrían ser muchas cosas. Deja el código nuevo a ver que puede estar fallando.

Comment: ahí lo tienes en una nueva respuesta, lo hice bien?